# Why i can not download VMware vSphere Hypervisor 5.1

Tags: hypervisor

Guys i have server HP Proliant DL160 G6 and i am trying to download VMware vSphere Hypervisor 5.1 but i can not.

I am trying to download it from the official website of vmware but it only allows me to download VMware vSphere Hypervisor 6.0 which is newer unsupported version for my server.

Can you please give me any download links and advices how i can find and download this version of VMware vSphere Hypervisor ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is NOT the kind of question this site was designed for!

Comment: Come on Tony, what are you using G6 hardware for?

Comment: @tombull89 G6 hardware is okay to use. G5 is no longer appropriate for anything, but a G6 is a good budget option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Googles ["ESXi 5.5 download"](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=esxi+5.1+download&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).
- Gets result with [direct download link](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=285&downloadGroup=VCL-VSP510-ESXI-51U3#product_downloads) for ESXi version 5.1 Update 3.
- Chooses option for [HP ProLiant-specific VMware build](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=HP-ESXI-5.1.0U3-GA&productId=285) because it contains the drivers and management features for your particular server.

Go from there.

Comment: Thank you so much. But after that from where i can download the client ? Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Stop trolling us, this site is for professional sysadmins, who tend to know how to google things.

Comment: @TonyStark After you install ESXi and connect to the host via https, you can get a download link for the vSphere client. Or... just Google it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/my-downloads

Go to "VMware vSphere Hypervisor 5", expand it and click "View downloads and licenses". This is if you previously downloaded it, if not check out:

[The direct link](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VSPHERE-HYPERVISOR-51-EN&productId=290)